# Returning list of null-terminated strings from external function into .NET

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, pinvoke

I am trying to call an external C++ function using VB.NET (answers in C# are fine, I can convert back) which returns a list of device names. This comes in the form of a pointer to a null-terminated array of null-terminated char arrays (correct me if I've misunderstood what I'm dealing with) with a function signature:

```
long GetNames(char*** names)
```

Most of the answers to similar questions I've found have involved something more like:

```
long GetNames(char** names, int length)
```

It appears from what I've read that I need to give it an IntPtr but I'm uncertain as to how this should be initialized, and in my case I don't know the length of the array. At the moment, in the VB module, I have:

```
<DllImport("MyExternal.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Function GetNames(ByRef names as IntPtr) As UInteger
End Function
```

I've tried calling the function by passing an IntPtr initialized as `IntPtr.Zero` or using `Marshall.AllocHGlobal`, but I always get an `AccessViolationException`.

Any ideas on how I should be calling this function and how I get the return value into a managed string array would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've found a sample function call in native C as follows:

```
char **tmplist;
GetNames(&tmplist)
```

Comment: You will need to allocate at least the array of `char*`. You may also be required to allocate the `char*` items that make up this array. What does the documentation to `GetNames` say on the matter.

Comment: This is the description for the function:

"List available devices. This function returns a pointer to a NULL terminated list of device names. The pointer should be freed later with FLIFreeList(). Each device name in the returned list includes the filename needed by FLIOpen(), a separating semicolon, followed by the model name or user assigned device name."

This is what it gives for the `names` parameter:

"Pointer to where the device name list will be placed."

Comment: Your `GetNames` looks fine in that case. At what point do you get the AV? As you call `GetNames`, or when you work with what it returns? Do you know what the return value signifies? Is it an error code?

Comment: AV is thrown when `GetNames` is called. The return value does signify an error code (0 = success, non-0 = failure - nothing more specific than this), but the execution does not continue beyond the call anyway and I can't handle the exception with `try...catch`.

Comment: Have you got any sample calling code in C? This one has me pretty puzzled. You don't need to worry about initializing names since it is an out value.

Comment: Your VB code matches the C++ code to the best of my understanding. Do you need to initialize the DLL perhaps? Is that what's missing from your .net program.

Answer (score -1):

*** would mean Pointer to a pointer to a pointer, which is very uncommon. 
I would expect that you are dealing with a pointer to pointer in c term which is a ByRef Call of a StringBuilder. If you do not receive the length you might need to do pointer arithmetics on your own until you find the null.